# How can I setup a Node.js WebJob with a Service Bus trigger?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

According to this article, Azure App Services WebJobs supports Node.js:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles

I need to trigger my node.js webjob from Service Bus, similiar in the way that Azure Functions can be triggered.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus-readme

How can I setup a Node.js WebJob with a Service Bus trigger?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you created a hello world node.js webjob? I don't see a problem described here. You've linked to the .Net service bus API. You probably want the javascript one if you want to trigger from node: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thank you for help. I've tried a Node.JS WebJob with a cron trigger. Works well. I am well aware of how to work with service bus using its Node.JS or even raw REST calls.   But please consider that the focus of this post is to leverage WebJob's service bus trigger in Node.JS - similar to what we have in Azure Functions.

Comment: Your question is: _I need a Service Bus trigger form my Node.js job_ can you clarify? Do you mean: _I need to send a message on Service Bus from my Node.js WebJob_ If so, it seems like you just need to write some node.js code to do that and run it in your webjob

Comment: Question: "Do you mean: I need to send a message on Service Bus from my Node.js WebJob? " Answer: No. This is a WebJob trigger scenario and concept.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify to describe exactly what you are trying to do? Are you instead trying to trigger your webjob from service bus?

Comment: I need to configure WebJobs such that it calls my code when a message appears in my Service Bus queue. Azure Functions can do that very well hence I expect WebJobs can do it.

Comment: I will edit your question and provide that clarification. You can re edit it if you like.

Comment: Question: " Are you instead trying to trigger your webjob from service bus?" Answer: YES.

Comment: OK so you need to capture messages from a service bus in node.js, and the code to do that is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues#receive-messages-from-a-queue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I have that code and that is not what I am looking for in this question. I need a service bus trigger. WebJobs Triggers are like push notification. Please see this for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

Comment: Here is the specific trigger code associated with the link you just posted next to _Run a function when a Service Bus queue or topic message is created_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example compare that to the node.js specific example that I already posted. Functionally there is no difference. Both samples use a connection string and a queue name and call a function when a message arrives.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I really appreciate you are helping me, but that is an Azure Function example that I reviewed in detail before I post this question. Azure function is built on top of the WebJob SDK. However that example does not work on jobs hosted on App Services.

Comment: OK. As you have probably gathered I have never done this I'm just researching on the fly. When you tried that node.js sample code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues#receive-messages-from-a-queue inside a webjob what happened? Perhaps that could help us understand what the problem is. As I see it, all of these are services that interact through API's. Any generic node.js code that captures service bus messages should run in any host (azure function, webjob, docker, kubernetes) with some refinements.